# Call custom JS alert inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php, alert

I use a custom alert javascript. I want to call this javascript inside a php. I got a basic alert to work but I cannot get the custom one to work.

This code works. It opens an alert window if my file path is empty

```
    <?php

$albums_json_file1 = site_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'users' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $username . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'main.json';
 if (!empty($albums_json_file1))

 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('message')</script>"
 ?>
```

This code does not work

```
    <?php

$albums_json_file1 = site_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'users' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $username . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'main.json';
if (!empty($albums_json_file1))

echo "<script> swal('REGISTRATION SUCCESS!', 'You are now being redirected to the payment screen!', 'success'); </script>"
  ?>
```

In my webpage I have the script source for the custom alert and if I just add this code in my webpage the popup alert works BUT I need it to check the site path and return the alert only if it is empty.

Here is the regular script. If I put this in the body of my webpage the alert pops up.

```
<script>

swal("REGISTRATION SUCCESS!", "You are now being redirected to the     payment screen!", "success");

</script>
```

Comment: Well are you calling the method before it is loaded?

Comment: Can you check the error in Chrome's firebug console

Comment: Can you please show the actual fuill code of what you are doing, these snippets are very dependent on the context they are placed in. Order of execution matters here.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `type='text/javascript'` just as you have it in the code that works ? So it becomes `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>swal('REGISTRATION SUCCESS!', 'You are now being redirected to the payment screen!', 'success'); </script>";`

Comment: @talk2toyin Adding `type='text/javascript'` will make zero difference....

Comment: it will if you're using a browser from 1992 :p\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your html is loading top to bottom.

Move the declaration of `swal()` to the header so it can be used anywhere in the body.

So your PHP echo is probably before you declare `swal()`

**example:**

```
<script>swal('Does not work');</script>
<script>
var swal = function(txt){
    alert(txt);
}
</script>
<script>swal('Works');</script>
```

The reason `alert();` works is because that works in your entire Document.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I feel like a fool. I had the php script in the head tag. I moved it into the body and it worked fine.

Comment: **note** As *your mom* mentions  loading scripts any other place than at the bottom will block parallel loading of other resources. So when performance is an issue, find solutions on how to move everything to the bottom.

Comment: so glad i chose this name lmaoooo +1 just for that comment

Comment: suggestion though: "the reason alert works is because it's a native javascript function and it's available in your entire docuemnt"

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, you will always get an alert because the way you wrote it, the string will never be empty. You ought to check if it creates a valid file path instead of checking if the string is empty (which it never will be). Use `file_exists()` instead of `empty()`.

I'm willing to bet the problem is that your filepath that you are generating is not correct.

---

EDIT - I'm not allowed to comment, but in response to the other answer - putting JS in the header is bad practice. It will slow down page load. If this indeed the issue, you ought to put an onload call in the **footer** and put all your javascript inside of it.

```
window.onload = function(){
    // Put codes here
};
```

So that the page content is loaded before doing any scripting.

That said, this isn't the issue you're having since you say that putting your `swal()` call in the **body** manually works.

Comment: It's not simply bad practice. It is a practice you would avoid when you have a lot of resources that need parallel loading in your page.  It's not the `empty` issue, both his conditions are exactly the same. It's a declaration issue. This guy is printing script tags with function calls with PHP, he needs to know what is going wrong, which is there being a undeclared method.

Comment: there are exceptions to every rule, @TimDev - but there's no reason to believe this is one of those exceptions.

Comment: I will add your comment under my answer as helpful. But indeed an exception to the best practice of moving script to the bottom is when people are printing content with JS or JS itself in the middle of the body. Which he is obviously doing (probably a lot more). He is safer with just learning that he hasn't declared it yet and what is actually not working. I understand you wanting to go much further in explaining. But sometimes it's best to keep it simple and stick to the problem, he is not in a position he will understand or even encounter parallel loading times as a problem.

Comment: lol, tim, i'm not in the practice of assuming everyone on the internet is retarded. i understand and respect your opinion, but the concept of putting your code in an onload function is not that complex :P